# Smooth Scrolling and Anchor Tags Issue

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, smooth-scrolling, rel

I am having a very odd issue and also finding it difficult to implement smooth scrolling on my single page website.

You can view my site [HERE](http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~tclar051/webprog/CW5/index.php)

---

Firstly, Is the strange anchor issue, when I click the link in the hamburger menu, the link appears in my address bar (which I would like to get rid of at some point) but when I scroll down the page it just keep being stuck on that div only I cannot scroll the page freely.

Secondly, I can't seem to implement any smooth scrolling techniques which I find on the net so far and I would really appreciate a little hint as to what I am doing wrong. I have tried to put `name=""` and `rel=""` into the `<li>` and `<a>` elements (adjusting the smooth scroll code accordingly but still nothing.

Please find reference [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

I am a bit of a newbie with javascript so maybe i am not doing something simple here.

Thanks in advance!

Terry

Comment: PS: Currently I have commented out the smooth scroll which you will find on script.js

Comment: I can't seem to find the problem ? can you share the code snippet for the page ?

Comment: I see that sorry, Just re-uploaded the site and you should be able to see the problem now

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to some other students I found that the issues is due to the html and body CSS. I needed them to both have height auto and min-hight 100%.

Although this still does resolve the issue with the revealOnScroll. I need to tweak this code I think as it isn't able to then calculate the offset().top